# Year-To-Date for Previous Years (Same Period Last Year)

Tags: sql, oracle, date-range

I've got transaction data spanning 3 years and I would like to report on performance for the different years on a Year-To-Date basis.

The data is like:

```
REP_NAME : SECTION : AMOUNT : DATE
Mark     : Sec1    : 2,000  : 01/10/2016
Jane     : Sec2    : 1,400  : 02/12/2017
```

And so on...

What I want to do is write a query that will group all the amounts per year but being controlled by the current date of the current year.

```
2016 : 2017 : 2018
2500 : 2300 : 3400
```

Showing, YTD for 2018 is 3400 (i.e. between 01/01/2018 - 29/03/2018), 
but same period the last two years (between 01/01/2017 - 29-03-2017) 
and (01/01/2016 and 29/03/2016) the collection was 2,300 and 2,500 respectively.

I hope this is clear. I am using Oracle Database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just filter those values where either the date is in an earlier month of the year or the date is in the same month of the year on an earlier-or-same day of the month:

```
SELECT EXTRACT( YEAR FROM "DATE" ) AS year,
       SUM( AMOUNT ) AS total_year_to_date_amount
FROM   your_table
WHERE  (  EXTRACT( MONTH FROM "DATE" ) < EXTRACT( MONTH FROM SYSDATE )
       OR (   EXTRACT( MONTH FROM "DATE" ) =  EXTRACT( MONTH FROM SYSDATE )
          AND EXTRACT( DAY   FROM "DATE" ) <= EXTRACT( DAY   FROM SYSDATE )
          )
       )
AND    "DATE" >= ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YEAR' ), -24 )
GROUP BY EXTRACT( YEAR FROM "DATE" );
```

or you can explicitly set the ranges:

```
SELECT EXTRACT( YEAR FROM "DATE" ) AS year,
       SUM( AMOUNT ) AS total_year_to_date_amount
FROM   your_table
WHERE  "DATE" BETWEEN TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YEAR' )
                  AND SYSDATE
OR     "DATE" BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YEAR' ), -12 )
                  AND ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -12 )
OR     "DATE" BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YEAR' ), -24 )
                  AND ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -24 )
GROUP BY EXTRACT( YEAR FROM "DATE" );
```

*(Note: the first query will include all results from the current day-of-the-year - i.e. 00:00 - 23:39 - whereas the second query only include results from the current day-of-the-year that are between 00:00 and the current time. You could give similar behaviour to the second query - one method is by using `TRUNC( "DATE" )`.)*

Answer (score 0):

You want to only consider certain days, i.e. January first till current day. So write a WHERE clause for this, looking at month and day, ignoring the year.

```
where to_char(date, 'mmdd') <= to_char(sysdate, 'mmdd')
```

Then you want sums per year. So group by year.

```
select
  extract(year from date) as year,
  sum(amount) as total
from mytable
where to_char(date, 'mmdd') <= to_char(sysdate, 'mmdd')
group by extract(year from date)
order by extract(year from date);
```